# Get futures symbol list with CCXT nodeJS

Tags: node.js, cryptocurrency, ccxt

Hi I want to get futures symbol list of coinex broker but exchange.loadMarkets only load spot symbols

Answer (score -1):

```
const ccxt = require ('ccxt');

console.log ('CCXT Version:', ccxt.version);

async function main () {

    const exchange = new ccxt.coinex ({
        // 'apiKey': '...',
        // 'secret': '...',
        'options': {
            'defaultType': 'swap',
        },
    });

    const markets = await exchange.loadMarkets ();
    console.log (markets);

};

main ();
```